# How to add new page in Magento2.3.4

Tags: magento2, customization

I'd like to show page when click menu item(a tag).
I use old header and footer and I'd like to change content.
where to add code? app/code/.. or app/design/frontend/..

Answer (score 0):

you can create a page from the admin panel.
Go to the admin Content>Pages and create a new page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RfmG.png)
then you will add content and URL for this page